# Does "as" mean "because" in "Just then, people start cheering and applauding as Steve steps up on the karaoke stage"?

Tags: grammar, sentence-construction, sentence-meaning, present-perfect

Does my sentence mean what I want it to mean?

> Just then, people start cheering and applauding **as** Steve steps up on the karaoke stage and takes the microphone.

Written like this, does it mean that people started cheering and applauding **because** Steve got up on the stage?

Comment: It doesn't mean that, but leaves the reader to conclude it. Maybe they started cheering because anyone got up there.

Comment: I agree that it doesn't mean that. The *as* here means *at the same time as*, not *because*.

Comment: If you want the sentence to mean like it so do one thing, remove 'Just then', make that 'start' as 'started' and  change 'steps' to 'stepped' and also 'takes' to 'took'.

Comment: "Just then" sounds weird to me when the rest of the sentence is in the present tense - "then" refers to a past event. "Just now" or "Right now" would be better.

Answer (score 2):

Here, "as" means at the same time. Unless there was some context to doubt it I'd assume that people at a karaoke night will clap each new participant.  They aren't clapping because **Steve** got on stage.  They are clapping because **someone** got on stage.

But the text doesn't say any of that. It only says the clapping was at the same time as Steve getting on stage. Everything else is inferred.

This demonstrates the difference between direct meaning, and what can be inferred from context and our common sense. We use lots of clues and context to understand the meaning of any sentence. You don't need to tell everything to your reader, you only need to give them enough to fill in the gaps from their understanding of the world.